# Detecting Object/Person in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab, I am working on a project which will take input an image like this
[image: passport image with blue background]

as we can see it has a plain background (blue), and system will generate it's passport size image with given ratios, first I am working to separate background and person, the approach I searched is like if there is a blue in combinations of `rgb` matrices of image, then it is background, and rest is a person, but I am little bit confused that if this approach is correct or not, if it is correct then how can I find that current pixel is blue or not, how can I do it with matlab function `find`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to crop your image based on person's face, then there is no need in separating the background from the foreground. Nowadays you will easily find ready implementations of face detection, so, unless you want to implement your own method because the ready one fails, this should be a non-issue. See:

```
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Yellow, Thick}], Opacity[0], 
   Rectangle @@@ 
    FindFaces[img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSwzj.jpg"]]}]]
```

[image]

Supposing the face is detected correctly, you can expand/retract its bounding box to match the size you are after.

Comment: brother do you have any reference to this function ? or any other details, because its not working, its giving me some syntax error.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFaces.html, truly a black-box. You will find much better described routines elsewhere.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz I couldn't care less, really. Just search for it. Here is an example after 1 second: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19912-open-cv-viola-jones-face-detection-in-matlab